# How to enrich the payload with an object from MongoDB (camel-mongodb)

Tags: mongodb, apache-camel, enterprise-integration

I'm trying to pull object from MongoDb and ADD it to my current payload and save it in another database:

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception
{
    from(kafkaEndpoint)
            .convertBodyTo(DBObject.class)
            .enrich("mongodb:mongoDb?database=myDbName1&collection=UserColl&operation=findOneByQuery",
                    (original, external) -> {
                        DBObject originalBody = original.getIn().getBody(DBObject.class);
                        DBObject externalBody = external.getIn().getBody(DBObject.class);

                        Map<String, DBObject> map = new HashMap<String, DBObject>();
                        map.put("original", originalBody);
                        map.put("external", externalBody);

                        original.getIn().setBody(map);
                        return original;
                    })
            .to("mongodb:mongoDb?database=myDbName2&collection=UserColl&operation=insert");
}
```

The problem that *enrich* fetch the query from the In.body that holds my original object...

So how can I pass query (*{"entity.id": ""}*) to *enrich(mongoldb:...)* and preserve original object to merge it with results?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception
    {
        from(kafkaEndpoint)
                .convertBodyTo(DBObject.class)
                .enrich("direct:findOneByQuery",     // <-------
                        (original, external) -> {
                            DBObject originalBody = original.getIn().getBody(DBObject.class);
                            DBObject externalBody = external.getIn().getBody(DBObject.class);

                            Map<String, DBObject> map = new HashMap<String, DBObject>();
                            map.put("original", originalBody);
                            map.put("external", externalBody);

                            original.getIn().setBody(map);
                            return original;
                        })
                .to("mongodb:mongoDb?database=myDbName2&collection=UserColl&operation=insert");

    }

    from("direct:findOneByQuery")
            .process(new Processor()
            {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception
                {
                    DBObject body = exchange.getIn().getBody(DBObject.class);
                    DBObject query = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
                            .append("entity._id", body.get("_id"))
                            .get();

                    exchange.getIn().setBody(query);
                }
            })
            .to("mongodb:mongoDb?database=myDbName1&collection=UserColl&operation=findOneByQuery");

 //
```

Comment: I've been trying to use this method, however I always get "No Consumers available on endpoint: direct://findOneByQuery". Is this something you encountered as well?

Comment: The other error that occurs if I try to use the mongodb component in "enrich" is this: 

"Failed to create Producer for endpoint: mongodb3 nullPointerException"